# toggle sql column on null JOIN value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, case

So I query a table called markers where I join to a table that contains edits of those markers and select the most recent edit from the table (table name: content_edits). However, not all markers have edits (and return thus return null in the query) so I would like to default to the date which which the marker was created on. This query properly grabs those two date values, but I would like them in one column name so I can sort the column to return the most recent dates.

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.description, m.directions, m.type, m.date_create, ce.date_decide
FROM markers AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT entity_id, entity_type, max(date_decide) as date_decide
   FROM content_edits
   WHERE status=1 
   GROUP BY entity_id, entity_type) ce ON ce.entity_id=m.id
LIMIT 500
```

I assume the answer would have some flavor of 'IF null THEN m.date_create`, but I don't have much idea where this would go or of the proper syntax.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` with `IS NULL` check:

```
CASE WHEN ce.date_decide IS NULL THEN m.date_create ELSE ce.date_decide END
```

In case you are using SQL Server 2012 and later (you have `sql-server` tag), you can yous `iif` function :

```
IIF( ce.date_decide IS NULL, m.date_create, ce.date_decide )
```

As your question is also tagged `mysql` then you can use `if` :

```
IF( ce.date_decide IS NULL, m.date_create, ce.date_decide )
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. On mySQL. Where does this snippet get added? at the end of the statement.

Comment: @ambe5960 : instead of `m.date_create, ce.date_decide`. And also, glad to help you.)